# loging out of site if navigating to other pages in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an issue when i am loging in to site after clicking on other menu tabs it is automatically loging out and if i wait for few minutes refresh and then login tabs are working fine.If i logout and login again and i click on other tabs geting loged out. I am not understanding where i need to check the code.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
# POST /resource/sign_in
def create    
respond_to do |format|
  format.json do
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    return render :json => resource
  end
  format.html do
    super
  end
end
end  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think issue it related to your authenticity_token

If you make a links in menu with the help of Rails form helper then You will not face this issue

Comment: This answer is also work for me when i am on rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the default in controller

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

to

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

will also solve problem in rails 4

Comment: ( in my file the code is like this )                                                                         class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      include SimpleCaptcha::ControllerHelpers

      protect_from_forgery                                                                      should i change it to exception or null_session